# Valgrind found 3 memory leaks but I can't figure out where they are

Tags: c++, valgrind

I tried to implement the basic String class by myself and it's working fine, but Valgrind says there are 3 memory leaks and I can't figure out where and why. I really tried to delete everything after it isn't used anymore (I have started using Valgrind today).
Now I'm really concerned about my basic C/C++ memory management knowledge. I made a comment to the places in the code where Valgrind found a leak (//VALGRIND). I've also uploaded a screenshot of this error message
[click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6IuH.png).

EDIT: I have updated the screenshot, so you can see the full output.

StringT.h

```cpp
template<typename char_type = char>
class StringT {
public:

 explicit StringT(const char_type *str) {
        if (str != nullptr) {
            size_t len = strlen(str);
            m_str = new char_type[len + 1]; //VALGRIND: 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
            strcpy(m_str, str);
        }
    }

   ~StringT() {
        delete [] m_str;
    }


StringT(const StringT & other) {
        size_t len = 0;
        if (other.m_str) len = strlen(other.m_str);
        m_str = new char_type[len + 1]; //VALGRIND: 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
        strcpy(m_str, other.m_str);
    }

    StringT(StringT && other) noexcept {
        m_str = other.m_str;
        other.m_str = nullptr;
    }


     StringT & operator+=(const StringT &other) {
        if (other.m_str == nullptr) //when other str is empty just return current Str
            return *this;

        const size_t mysize{m_str ? strlen(m_str) : 0}; // check if not null then call strlen
        const size_t osize{other.m_str ? strlen(other.m_str) : 0};

        char *newStr = new char_type[osize + mysize + 1]; //VALGRIND: 11 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
        newStr[0] = '\0'; //strcat searches for '\0', so newStr has to be a valid String

        if (m_str) strcat(newStr, m_str);
        if (other.m_str) strcat(newStr, other.m_str);

        delete[] m_str; //delete old string
        m_str = newStr; //set member to new concatenated str

        return *this;
    }

    size_t length() const {
        if (!m_str) return 0;
        return strlen(m_str);
    }


    friend
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, StringT<> &other) {
        if (other.m_str) out << other.m_str;
        return out;
    }

private:
    char_type *m_str{nullptr};
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main() {

    const char *cArr = "Hello";
    const char *cArr2 = "World";
    StringT<char> hello(cArr);
    StringT<char> world(cArr2);
    StringT<char> emptyStr;

    std::cout << "hello: " << hello << std::endl;
    std::cout << "world: " << world << std::endl;
    std::cout << "emptyStr: " << emptyStr << std::endl;

    StringT<char> hCopy(hello);
    StringT<char> wMove(std::move(world));

    std::cout << "hCopy: " << hello << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hCopy: " << hCopy << std::endl;
    std::cout << "world: " << world << std::endl;
    std::cout<<  "wMove: " << wMove << std::endl;
    std::cout<<  "lenMove: " << wMove.length() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<  "lenEmptyStr: " << emptyStr.length() << std::endl;

    hello += wMove;
    std::cout<<  "hello += world: " << hello << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `StringT() { delete [] m_str;}` shouldn't that be a destructor?

Comment: Please post diagnostics as _text_, not pictures. Otherwise you discriminate against the blind. And, yes, there are blind people here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delete is here:

```
StringT() {
    delete [] m_str;
}
```

But that's a constructor, not a destructor.

Comment: Oh my bad! Thank you for your answer! But even after after adding the "~", the problem still occurs.. :/

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, the `delete` needs to be in the destructor. However, the proper solution to your problem is to not do memory management manually in this case. You should be using `std::unique_ptr` for your `m_str` member:

```
std::unique_ptr<char_type[]> m_str;
```

This frees you from having to `new` and `delete` manually. This also helps protects against memory leaks in case of exceptions. Even if you `delete` everything you allocated, you can still have memory leaks if an exception occurs between the `new` and the `delete`. `unique_ptr` helps in preventing this kind of leak.

Your class only needs small changes:

```
template<typename char_type = char>
class StringT {
public:
    StringT()
    {}

    explicit StringT(const char_type *str)
    {
        if (str != nullptr) {
            size_t len = strlen(str);
            m_str = std::make_unique<char_type[]>(len + 1);
            strcpy(m_str.get(), str);
        }
    }

    StringT(const StringT & other)
    {
        size_t len = 0;
        if (other.m_str)
            len = strlen(other.m_str.get());
        m_str = std::make_unique<char_type[]>(len + 1);
        strcpy(m_str.get(), other.m_str.get());
    }

    StringT(StringT && other) noexcept
    {
        m_str = std::move(other.m_str);
    }

    StringT & operator+=(const StringT &other)
    {
        if (other.m_str == nullptr)
            return *this;

        const size_t mysize{m_str ? strlen(m_str.get()) : 0};
        const size_t osize{strlen(other.m_str.get())};

        auto newStr = std::make_unique<char_type[]>(osize + mysize + 1);
        newStr[0] = '\0';

        if (m_str)
            strcat(newStr.get(), m_str.get());
        strcat(newStr.get(), other.m_str.get());

        m_str = std::move(newStr);
        return *this;
    }

    size_t length() const
    {
        if (!m_str)
            return 0;
        return strlen(m_str.get());
    }

    friend
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, StringT<> &other)
    {
        if (other.m_str)
            out << other.m_str.get();
        return out;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<char_type[]> m_str;
};
```

You will notice that there are no calls to `new` or `delete` in this code. `m_str` will automatically delete allocated memory on its own when needed.

Comment: In fairness the right thing to do is use `std::string` so presumably all this manual stuff is part of an exercise :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed :-) Although I still like to teach people how to correctly implement "low level" dynamic arrays with the `[]` version of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Hi Nikos, thank you for your answer :) Yes, @LightnessRacesinOrbit was right this is just an exercise to get a better understanding how things work under the hood. I guess I just have to accept , that there is always a possibility to get leaks with raw pointers even if everything was deleted correctly.

Comment: If you delete everything correctly then you won't get leaks... but doing it correctly is often very difficult.